# How can I create a file with the list of files in a directory in FTP site using ncftp or ftp?

Tags: ftp, io-redirection

I want to list files and create a file with the list of files in FTP site.

```
$ ncftp ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov
[FTP SITE MESSAGE]
ncftp / > ls
```

Then, I would see a list of directories.  How can I create a local file with the list of FTP site files?

Answer (score 0):

I've realized that there are more sub-programs in ncftp.  I could use ncftpls to get a list of files from FTP sites.

```
$ ncftpls -1 ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ > 1
```

This would create a file named "1" with file names at the top of the FTP site.